# Dynamically change the size of node-red-dashboard template node

Tags: css, html, node-red

When using a template node and dynamically adding content, what is the best way to size the node? For example I have a dynamically sized div that I pass msg.payload.divInfo:

```
<div>
    {{msg.payload.divInfo}}
</div>
```

Since the div has no height attribute, I only see one line of the info and have to scroll. If I set the height of the div statically:

```
<div style="height: 130px;">
    {{msg.payload.divInfo}}
</div>
```

It shows all the content. If I try to set the height of the div by:

```
<div style="height: {{msg.payload.divHeight}}px;">
    {{msg.payload.divInfo}}
</div>
```

I still only see one line.

The div cannot be static height.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```html
<div style="height:auto;">
</div>
```

or

```html
<div style="height:auto; overflow:auto">
</div>
```

Comment: The parent div, controlled by node-red, is setting the size of the div to a certain height even though I left the node size set to auto. It seems to be that it isn't doing the calculation using msg.payload.divHeight until after it decides the size of the parent div. For now I'm doing an ugly workaround by using .parent.style.height = "auto" but I just want to see if there is something I'm missing in configuring the template node.

Comment: It's been a long time, but am facing the same issue, and it will be really helpful if you could show how you added this to the template